# Shopify Webhook integrate with mule

Tags: shopify, mule, integration, webhooks, mulesoft

I have created REST API for POST HTTP and import it to Mule applications then deploy it to CloudHub and used that URL in Shopify Webhook then trying to get data but unable to get data from postman...

Is this a correct way to use Webhook in Mule applications...

Comment: Please clarify what is the actual issue and provide information. What are you requesting with postman? If the Mule application is not responding to Postman then remove everything about Shopify.

Answer (score 0):

Since Mule runtime doesn't has a concept of webhooks there is not a correct or incorrect way to use them. Mule applications can listen to HTTP requests. If another system sends an HTTP request to the correct URL that the Mule application is listening it should work. To the Mule application it doesn't matter if it is coming from a webhook, another application, Postman or whatever HTTP client implementation.